# How are HTML tags converted to HtmlControl?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Suppose I have this markup:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a runat="server" id="myLink" href="<%# Container.DataItem %>">Here</a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

In the code-behind, I can find out that `<a>` is converted to `HtmlAnchor`:

```
private void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    HtmlAnchor myLink = (HtmlAnchor)Repeater1.FindControl("myLink");
}
```

But how does the compiler know that `<a>` is `HtmlAnchor`? Is it hard-coded in the compiler?

If I write

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <Foo href="<%# Container.DataItem %>">Here</a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and want the `<Foo>` tag to be converted to my `HtmlFoo` class, how do I achieve that?

I just want to have a deeper understanding of the compilation process behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can learn a lot about the internals of ASP.NET by delving into the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web,namespaces).

It turns out that the mapping from unprefixed HTML tags to HtmlControl subclasses is hard-coded in an internal class called [HtmlTagNameToTypeMapper](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/HTMLTagNameToTypeMapper.cs,28):

```
static Hashtable _tagMap;

Type ITagNameToTypeMapper.GetControlType(string tagName, IDictionary attributeBag) {
    Type controlType;

    if (_tagMap == null) {
        Hashtable t = new Hashtable(10, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        t.Add("a", typeof(HtmlAnchor));
        t.Add("button", typeof(HtmlButton));
        t.Add("form", typeof(HtmlForm));
        // [and much more...]
        _tagMap = t;
    }

    // [...]
}
```

GetControlType is called by another internal class called [MainTagNameToTypeMapper](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/TagNameToTypeMapper.cs,528):

```
int colonIndex = tagName.IndexOf(':');
if (colonIndex >= 0) {
    // [...]
}
else {
    // There is no prefix.
    // Try the Html mapper if allowed
    if (fAllowHtmlTags) {
        return _htmlMapper.GetControlType(tagName, attribs);
    }
}
```

There's no public API to register more unprefixed HTML control types.

On a more localized scale, it *is* possible for a parent control to customize how the tag names of its child controls are interpreted. To do this, derive from ControlBuilder, override [GetChildControlType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.controlbuilder.getchildcontroltype(v=vs.110).aspx), and decorate the parent control class with the [[ControlBuilder(typeof(...)] attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.controlbuilderattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

When you add `runat="server"` to a control in ASP.NET, a corresponding variable of type `HtmlControl` (or some subclass thereof) is automatically added to your page (in the designer file). That way you can access that control as a variable. For most common HTML controls, there are subclasses of HtmlControl (such as `HtmlAnchor` for anchor/link tags). Other controls (such as `<div>`) get the `HtmlGenericControl` type. For those, you specify the tag (`div`) as a property. So your Foo tag would get like a div: a variable of type `HtmlGenericControl` with a tag of "Foo".

**Edit:** this is for standard HTML elements. If you create an ASP control (such as `<asp:TextBox...>`, then the resulting variable will be a subclass or **WebControl** instead of **HtmlControl**.

Comment: "your Foo tag would get like a div: a variable of type HtmlGenericControl. " Can I change that? Is it possible to develop a HtmlFoo class so that <Foo> is converted to HtmlFoo?

Comment: You could create a UserControl. The markup would contain whatever you like. Then register that UserControl on your page, like this:
`<%@ Register Src="~/MyUserControl.ascx" TagPrefix="uc" TagName="MyUserControl"%>`
Then in your markup, you can use that usercontrol as follows:
`<uc:MyUserControl ...>`
It wouldn't let you add `<Foo ...>` and get an instance of your custom class behind the scenes, but as long as you were willing to deal with the notation of `<[prefix]:[name] ...>`, then you could more or less create whatever you like.

Comment: I have been doing lots of custom/user controls. I'm seeking the possibility to get rid of prefix. Or I ask in another way, how does compiler know <a> is HtmlAnchor? Is there an attribute specifying that?